# How to traverse to each Column in the same Row in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to traverse each column in the same row, I'm new to VBA and any help would be appreciated..

Here's my code:

```
Sub dural()
   Dim i As Long
   Dim j As Long

    i = 2

    Cells(1, i).Select

    For i = 2 To Columns.Count

    Cells(1, i + j).Select

    'Selection.Copy

    j = i + 1

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code would click on 16000+ cells. I know that's fun but does it have a purpose? Today's lesson: don't `Select` anything. Instead of `Cells(1, i).Select: Selection.Copy: Cells(2, i).Select: Selection.Paste` use the direct instruction `Cells(1, i).Copy Cells(2, i)`

Comment: @Variatus not sure if  `Cells(1, i).Copy Cells(2, i)` that's a good recommendation. Copy/ paste usually isn't a good recommendation, rather something like `Cells(2,i).Value = Cells(1,i).Value`

Comment: @Dean I appreciate your effort to introduce Mikhail to the difference between `copy` and `=`. However, even the superficial approach you chose shouldn't really be interjected into a talk about cell addressing. The question here is whether or not VBA has the capability to read or modify range objects other than the `Selection`. We all know that it does. Once that point has sunk in, but not today, Mikhail will surely come to the point you raise soon enough. At that time he may conclude that a prejudice against copy/paste is just an opinion without universal scope of application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luan Yi,
Your question states "trying to traverse each column in the same row";
the code below shows how to loop through each `Column`, or loop through
each cell in `Row 1` and use `.EntireColumn` to do something; without using `.Select`

'Use the `With statement` that meets your needs

```
'define your variables
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'change worksheet name as needed
Dim lCol As Long: lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'define last used column in row 1

    For i = 2 To lCol
        'If you want to loop through each column, you can use...
        With ws.Columns(i)
            'you can do something, for example using .Delete or .Copy, etc.
        End With

        'or

        'If you want to loop through each cell in row 1, the you can use...
        With ws.Cells(1, i)
            'you can do something, for example using .EntireColumn.Delete or .EntireColumn.Copy, etc.
        End With
    Next i
```